# Automatic break if variable IsEmpty

Tags: vba

I'm debugging some old code, Visual Basic 5.0, and I have the line
"**if x <> y then**" ... and the Locals Window shows that x is Variant/Empty.
(all variables are of type Variant)

Meaning that x is used without being initialized first, which I see as an error.
Is there a way of making Visual Basic treat using empty variables as error?

I know of IsEmpty() but that is not automatic checking of all the variables.

Comment: Can [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) do the trick?

Comment: There are variables that can't be used if you don't initialize first as arrays, but there are other variables that can be... Your only way is to check if the variable is empty or not. `If Range Is Nothing` `If Str = vbNullString`....

Comment: Sounds like you'll also need to initialize those variables. You could try using `Debug.Assert Not IsEmpty(x)`. That will highlight all the conditions where the variables are about to be used in an uninitialized state (then you can fix them).